# Best approach to update django project, track updates

Tags: python, django, performance, updates

**Hello Awesome People!**

I have a Django project, already hosted. the project contains lots of functionalities. Sometimes, when I update a part of the project, I don't remember where these updates might affect.

**Page 1**

```
 line 1: if obj.love_basket:
 line 2:     up.fan = True # as well
 line 3:     up.save()
```

After months, I want to remove `fan` attribute and replace it with `is_fan`

**Page 2**

```
 line 4: class UserProfile:
 line 5:     # fan = models.BooleanField()
 line 6:     is_fan = models.BooleanField()
```

This change will give an error in the future when a user hits `line 2`
*This is just an example.*

**How will I know where these changes may affect?**

Comment: I recommend using Pycharm for such refactors. There is Shift+F6 command for renaming. I'm not sure, but I believe you need Professional edition to have support for Django. After using that command I'd couble check by looking for string ".fan(" in the project (I'd also use Pycharm). BUT, you will miss something anyway and this is why you need good tests :-)

Comment: in **Sublime Text** i used to make a global search of the variable before removing it, but I think it's not the best approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Write unit tests!](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/) Things like that are an easy catch with a pretty simple unit test.

Comment: Ok, write unit tests. How to proceed when having a big project?

Comment: Well ideally, you write them along the way as you code. But if you have no unit tests so far, I recommend starting by picking the simplest page/route to test. That will get the momentum moving.

Comment: And in the future, every new route/feature you write, write a unit test to go along with it.